# Get back to ui thread in async callback method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm migrating more and more of my code to async/await and mostly it's smooth sailing.

However sometimes I arrive at the following situation and I'm not sure how it's "meant" to work with the async/await pattern:

```
    private async void My_EventHandler(object sender, Event ev)
    {
        // This event is raised by a background worker thread
        // Somehow we need to go back to ui thread here
        NotifyPropertyChange(Busy); // Or any other method that should run on ui thread
        await processEventAsync(ev);
        NotifyPropertyChange(Busy);
    }
```

Currently I'm doing an explicit Dispatcher/Invoke with an async lambda in these cases, but it seems dirty considering how clean everything else is with async/await.

So I guess the question is, is there something like this in C#?

```
await SwitchToUIThread();
```

Comment: It depend on the implementation  of  `processEventAsync`. Because if you don't start new tasks/threads manually (for example accessing some external resources database, files, web-services) then code execution should remain on the same UI thread

Comment: Well that's what the Dispatcher is for. An alternative would be to use a [Progress](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html) created on the UI thread and using its Report method to update the UI.

Comment: @Fabio the problem is that the code that invokes My_EventHandler is running on a background thread in the first place, so we're actually not on the ui thread at all.

Comment: @Fabio I don't understand your comment. The question clearly states, that the event handler is called by a background thread (= non-UI) and it shall call something that must run on UI-Thread ...

Comment: @Fildor if using the dispatcher is the right way to do it, I'm perfectly happy with that, I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious :)

Comment: Well, I'd add that it is probably beneficial for responsiveness to keep the code executed in the Dispatcher call as short as possible. But I wouldn't optimize prematurely, neither.

Comment: If you later decide to also switch from a dedicated background thread to a Task-Async method running on the TP, remember the "Progress" alternative. The link in my first comment is really worthwhile to read.

Comment: @Fildor I will, it looks good. Keeping this open if anyone else have input!

Comment: My point was that with `async-await` you can get rid of background worker. But it will work in case if job you do in background worker is accessing external resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the technique explained in https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2015/11/11/explicitly-switch-to-the-ui-thread-in-an-async-method/

Include SynchronizationContextAwaiter into your code.

Somewhere in your code capture the GUI context in syncContext variable which should be available to your event handler.

In the event handler, do

```
await syncContext;
```

Comment: Read the topmost comment on that article by Stephen Cleary ... BTW: That solution is not applicable here anyway: the Event Handler is already running on a background Thread.

Comment: @Fildor Read the article carefully: "Or perhaps you want to switch to the UI thread in a method that didn’t start on the UI thread."

Comment: OK, taking back that part. Still sharing Stephen's objection.

Comment: For the first part, read the last comment to the article: https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2015/11/11/explicitly-switch-to-the-ui-thread-in-an-async-method/#comment-83292

Comment: Yes, he disagrees. So? I'm still with Stephen. Also I think that solution would be too complex for this one very specific instant of the problem. "Keep It Simple".

Comment: In fact, using Progress for this purpose is more difficult.  You still need to capture the context (in Progress).  With Awaiter you just add a small class to your codebase.  With Progress you need to restructure your code, moving ui code to the place where Progress is been created.

Comment: He's refactoring his codebase anyway ... I don't know his codebase, so I cannot tell if it would be "more difficult" and so do you. Look, I don't say the solution should *not* be considered (mind that I did not downvote). Just *I* wouldn't use it - for the reasons given in Stephen's comment. You are free to disagree, of course.